# Incorrect table definition: there can only be one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: sql, database

I read that this error is normally caused by trying to have more than one primary key, but in my table that doesn't appear to be the case, I only have one primary key, `OfferID`:

```
CREATE TABLE PropertyOffers 
(
    OfferID INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (OfferID),
    ClientID INT(8) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    AgentID INT(8) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CONSTRAINT regstufk FOREIGN KEY (ClientID) REFERENCES Clients(ClientID),
    CONSTRAINT regstufk FOREIGN KEY (AgentID) REFERENCES Agents(AgentID),
    CONSTRAINT propertyoffer FOREIGN KEY (PropertyID) REFERENCES Properties(PropertyID)
);
```

I get this error:

> Incorrect table definition: there can only be one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: What part of the message do you not understand?  You have three `auto_increment` columns?

Comment: By "auto column" they mean "auto_increment column"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `auto_increment` on the column used as the primary key in the table.  Foreign keys would have the `AUTO_INCREMENT` (if appropriate) in their reference tables.

So:

```
CREATE TABLE PropertyOffers (
    OfferID INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (OfferID),
    ClientID INT(8),
    AgentID INT(8),
    PropertyId INT,  -- or whatever the type
    CONSTRAINT regstufk FOREIGN KEY (ClientID) REFERENCES Clients(ClientID),
    CONSTRAINT regstufk FOREIGN KEY (AgentID) REFERENCES Agents(AgentID),  
    CONSTRAINT propertyoffer FOREIGN KEY (PropertyID) REFERENCES Properties(PropertyID) 
);
```

You have a foreign key that references `PropertyID`, but it is not defined in the table.  You need a column before you can declare it as a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

I makes no sense to define the foreign key columns as auto-increment. The parent columns (presumably) are, but no the referencing columns.

Your table also appears to be missing the declaration of column `PropertyID`, which you are setting a foreign key constraint on.

So, probably:

```
CREATE TABLE PropertyOffers (
    OfferID INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (OfferID),
    ClientID INT(8),
    AgentID INT(8),
    PropertyID INT(8),
    CONSTRAINT regstufk FOREIGN KEY (ClientID) REFERENCES Clients(ClientID),
    CONSTRAINT regstufk FOREIGN KEY (AgentID) REFERENCES Agents(AgentID),
    CONSTRAINT propertyoffer FOREIGN KEY (PropertyID) REFERENCES Properties(PropertyID)
);
```